# Python2 socket.recvfrom() / recv() differences between LInux and Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, sockets, networking

I can successfully receive packets in Ubuntu 20.04 by calling `bind()` and receiving a message with `recvfrom()`. However, switching to Windows seems to have broken that. After clearing up a firewall issue, I can successfully receive the packet in Python 3.9, but I still cannot receive it in Python 2.7 (which is what my current program is using). When running in Python 2.7, it seems to get hung up on the `recv()` / `recvfrom()` call until I terminate it. 2.7 and 3.9 work fine in Ubuntu, so I seem to only be having this issue with Python 2.7 on Windows.

**UPDATE**: I did not think the IP address and port were important, as the code runs perfectly fine on Ubuntu and Windows using Python 3. I do not have access to the server-side of the code yet but will hopefully update later. What I do know is that the board is broadcasting to the particular port and IP address I have bound to below.

```
recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
recv_socket.bind(("192.168.11.149", 5155))
data = recv_socket.recv(1024) 
print(data)
```

I am connecting to the particular IP intentionally, instead of accepting all IP addresses. That IP is also the correct one shown in ifconfig/ipconfig on my Ubuntu and Windows OS (on the same machine) since I am hardwired to our board through that particular port.

Is there a change in behavior between Windows and Ubuntu that I am missing? Or a change between Python 2.7 and Python 3.9 that would cause the `recv()` call to freeze up like this?

Comment: What IP address are you binding to? What IP address are you broadcasting to?

Comment: In other words, make a [mcve].

Comment: @user207421 When I bind to an IP/Port, it is the same that the message is broadcasted to. I have updated my code to show the IP and port.

Comment: Sending UDP datagrams to 192.168.11.149 is not broadcasting. It is unicasting. You should generally bind to 0.0.0.0 unless you know what you're doing. Unless your Windows and Linux are co-resident in the same host its IP address *must* be different.

Comment: @user207421 That's fair; I will edit to correct the wording.
For this case, 0.0.0.0 will accomplish the same thing and although I'm not terribly concerned with the security risk, I also don't see how it will impact anything. It runs the same on Linux and does not address the issue on Windows.
Windows and Linux are running from the same machine and if/ipconfig are showing 192.168.11.149 for both (on the ethernet port I'm connected to, at least).

Answer (score 0):

No change, but giving an *actual* example of client and server code that breaks would go a long way to getting an answer as to the behavior you see.

Here's code that works in Python 2 and Python 3.  The client and server do not have to be the same version of Python.

server.py

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import socket

recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
recv_socket.bind(('',9999))
while True:
    data,addr = recv_socket.recvfrom(1024) 
    print(addr,'->',repr(data))
```

client.py

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(b'hello',('localhost',9999))
```

Comment: I've updated the client side of my example to list the IP and port. I am hoping to see the server-side of the code soon. Is there a way the server-side could be written that works fine in Python 2.7 in Ubuntu but not Windows?